# Idiom for from difficult situation to worse situation

Tags: word-choice, word-request, idioms

Is there an idiom that we can refer to say " going through from tough times to tougher(worst) times"

My own creation: From boiling oil to fire. Something like this.

Comment: @santosha..its possibly a duplicate. Have a look at this   https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31867/are-there-any-expressions-that-describe-going-from-a-bad-to-a-worse-situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a phrase "out of the frying pan and into the fire."

It conveys the image of a fish frying in a pan and it's very hot for it.
All of a sudden, the fish falls out of the pan and straight into the fire.

As hot as it was in the frying pan, it's a lot worse in the actual fire.
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_frying_pan_into_the_fire) for more.
This is a very common idiom for this idea.

Comment: Looks good. Any other choices?